# Single node hadoop -how to copy local filesystem file to hadoop file system

Tags: hadoop

I have installed hadoop. Now i am trying to copy one local file-system to hadoop file-system using below command.

> > hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /mnt/PRO/wvdial.conf hdfs://virus/mydata/hdfs/datanode/wvdial.conf

but I am getting below error.

> > copyFromLocal: Call From Virus/127.0.0.1 to Virus:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I gone through "http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused" documentation and I found that "Check that there isn't an entry for your hostname mapped to 127.0.0.1 or 127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts (Ubuntu is notorious for this) ".

Yes I have my host "Virus" mapped to 127.0.0.1 at /etc/hosts. I have installed hadoop on single node.So I have to map my host to 127.0.0.1. Now what change I should make my configuration so that I could copy my local filesyatem file to hdfs?

Please find hadoop configuration from my hadoop installation documentation "http://omsopensource.blogspot.in/search/label/Hadoop". I am using Fedora 19.

Comment: Oh my god, you have a virus :P

Comment: mapping 127.0.0.1 to localhost and your machines IP address to virus should make it work.

Comment: both(localhost and virus) are mapped to 127.0.0.1 as it is single node hadoop implementation as mentioned.